# Magento 2.2.4 unable to get customer session data

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

Here I am unable to get customer session data ($customerSession) it's working in Magento version 2.2.3 but not working 2.2.4 it return false when cacheable is false.

```
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Helper;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }



    public function getCustomerGroup() {
        if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $groups = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
            return $groups;
        }
        return '0';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It version specific issue in Magento 2.2.4 you can check here, 
Url :- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3294

```
<?php


namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Helper;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory
     */
    private $sessionFactory;


    /**
     * Data constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $sessionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $sessionFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->sessionFactory = $sessionFactory;
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {

       $customerId = $this->sessionFactory->create()->getCustomer()->getId();
       return $customerId;
    }


}
```

Comment: ok,i will check